# How to extract data using groupby under specific condition?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have a data set as such:

```
x = {'column1': ['a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','d'],
    'column2': [1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns = ['column1', 'column2'])
print (df)
```

How would i extract only data from column two that have value of one (like this):

```
x = {'column1': ['a','b','b','c','c','d'],
    'column2': [1,1,1,1,1,1]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns = ['column1', 'column2'])
print (df)
```

Also how would i count the number of 1's for each values in column 1 and make a new column and insert that information for respective indexes in coulmn_1(for example, how many 1's do index value a in column_1 have?).So it turns dataframe into this format:

```
x = {'column1': ['a','b','b','c','c','d'],
    'column2': [1,1,1,1,1,1],
 'column3': [1,2,2,2,2,1]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns = ['column1', 'column2','column3'])
print (df)
```

Answer (score 3):

First question:

```
df[df.column2==1].reset_index(drop=True)
```

will give you

```
    column1     column2
0   a   1
1   b   1
2   b   1
3   c   1
4   c   1
5   d   1
```

Second question:

```
df['column3'] = df.groupby('column1').transform(len)
```

will give you

```
    column1     column2     column3
0   a   1   1
1   b   1   2
2   b   1   2
3   c   1   2
4   c   1   2
5   d   1   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for compare like `==` and then [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = df[df['column2'].eq(1)]
df['column3'] = df['column1'].map(df['column1'].value_counts())
```

Alternative with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df['column3'] = df.groupby('column1')['column1'].transform('size')
```

---

```
print (df)
  column1  column2  column3
0       a        1        1
2       b        1        2
3       b        1        2
5       c        1        2
6       c        1        2
8       d        1        1
```

Last for default index use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  column1  column2  column3
0       a        1        1
1       b        1        2
2       b        1        2
3       c        1        2
4       c        1        2
5       d        1        1
```